# Floating rhubarb in cake

Tags: cake

What causes diced rhubarb to float from the bottom of glass pan (where it was placed under a cake mix) to the top of cake mixture while baking?

Answer (score 1):

Some doughs melt when heated, esp high fat doughs which rely on eggs/protein hardening, starch drying/thickening, or similar effects, and not gluten for structure.

And once the dough is molten, anything significantly lighter per cubic cm than itself will rise, anything significantly heavier will sink.

Comment: Oh, and... the rhubarb is wet (giving off water and/or steam, might dissolve or displace whatever is around it) and acidic (might activate leaveners prematurely, influence texture of nearby dough)...

Comment: It can be somewhat mitigated by tossing the rhubarb with some of the flour from the recipe just to lightly coat.